# Remove Edit and Create New View links from VF Page

Tags: apex, list, list-view, tab, actionlink

I have below VF Page which shows similar as List Views for Form_Requests_abv__c object. Now I want to hide **Edit** and **Create New View** link from the VF Page. Please suggest me a way out to achieve it. Thanks!

**Apex Page**

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Form_Requests_abv__c">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Form Requests" subTitle="Home" />
<apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:ListViews type="Form_Requests_abv__c" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list view setting is a user setting and work for all the objects that a user has access to not a single object.

You can remove the below setting from User permissions `Create and Customize List Views`. [Link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customviews.htm&type=0)

Just remember this will remove access to create/edit list views for all objects.

You can do it via `css`

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Form_Requests_abv__c">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="TEST " subTitle="Home" />
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:ListViews type="Form_Requests_abv__c" />
    <style>
    span.fFooter {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I just wanted to remove it on this page only if possible by css or any other javascript or any thing else.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks manjit! It worked for me! How did you find the syntax ffooter?

Comment: Right Click on the Create New View and Select Inspect Element. From there you can find it. It is somewhat a css hack.